# Trying to import XML file fails

Tags: xml, powershell, office365

I have exported settings from Office 365 (`Export-Clixml`) that I need to import now in a new tenant but it generates an error:

```
PS> [Byte[]]$Data = Get-Content -Path ".TransportRules.xml" -Encoding Byte -ReadCount 0
PS> Import-TransportRuleCollection -FileData $Data

There is no Unicode byte order mark. Cannot switch to Unicode.
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (File Data:String) [Import-TransportRuleCollection], XmlException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : [Server=DB5PR06MB1096,RequestId=f7825e85-da68-4cf4-a9cc-f201ffcc53ce,TimeStamp=7/6/2015 6:45:11 PM]
                          [FailureCategory=Cmdlet-XmlException]
                          39E0CC0E,Microsoft.Exchange.MessagingPolicies.Rules.Tasks.ImportTransportRuleCollection
+ PSComputerName        : outlook.office365.com
```

The file is using encoding utf-16 which could cause an issue?

Comment: If you used Export-Clixml to export it, why don't you use Import-Clixml to import it?  You can also generically import XML far easier with `[xml]$xml = Get-Content TransportRules.xml`

Comment: This is scripts from Microsoft.Add-Content $outfile "`n[Byte[]]$Data = Get-Content -Path `".TransportRules.xml`" -Encoding Byte -ReadCount 0"
Add-Content $outfile "`nImport-TransportRuleCollection -FileData $Data"

Comment: The script probably is fine.  It's the XML input that's wrong.  Export-Clixml is not a generic XML generator.  It's a way to serialize data between PowerShell sessions, so you could take an instance of a variable and save it to use again later.  If the XML file in question was generated with that, it's not going to be in a format that another cmdlet will recognize.

Comment: the script is there: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn801047%28v=exchg.150%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#BKMK_Collectdatafromthesourceorganization   and the import one here: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn801047%28v=exchg.150%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#BKMK_Addprotectoinsettings

Comment: Actually i have replaced utf-16 with utf-8 in the source file and i can import some settings now

Comment: @BaconBits Except for Import-Clixml which will recognize the format just fine.  For that matter, it is valid XML and can be imported just as I showed in my previous comment.  OTOH extracting the useful data is harder than just using Import-Clixml.